# How to Eliminate Datatables Warning(Cannot reinitialise DataTable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Hello i have created a table using the jquery datatable framework to display data.

automatically my datables are sorted into a form in which i do not want

so i did some research on how to disable sorting and then i get sorting disabled.

the problem now is when i disabled sorting i get a funny error :

*"DataTables warning: table id=datatable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3"*

so i do another round of research on why i am having this problem.

the problem is i am calling the dataTable() function twice on my page

so the solution should be to only call it once.

the second problem i have is i dont know where the first function has been called.

Reason : i am making use of a template and it does not state explicitly where this is defined.

how can i get rid of this error? is there any method.

please see my implementation for disabling sorting below which works for sorting but triggers that error

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#datatable').dataTable({
          "bSort": false,
          "bDestroy": true
       });
    });
```

what i am trying to achieve is display my datatable without sorting

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to destroy the existing DataTable before re-initializing it:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#datatable' ) ) {
    $( '#datatable' ).DataTable().destroy();
  }
  $( '#datatable' ).dataTable( {
    "bSort": false,
    "bDestroy": true
  } );
} );
```

Comment: Maybe it's the second call of `dataTable()` that gives the error? Do you have access to that, include the `destroy()` function there?

Comment: hmm i think i have it, but i dont just know whr it has been called, is there anyway to know and detect whr a function has been called within a page?

Comment: I would just suggest you search your JavaScript sources in the editor or the browser and look for `dataTable(`